# Typescript - Why should I rewrite all members to implement an interface?

Tags: oop, inheritance, typescript, interface

I have an interface with some optional variables like:

```
interface A {
    id: string;
    name?: string;
    email?: string;
    ...
}
```

What I want to do is that

```
class B implements A {
    constructor(x: string, y: string, ...) {
        this.id = x;
        this.name = y;
        ...
    }

    getName(): string {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

I don't want to rewrite all members that I will use and I need some members to stay optional. Each interface will be implemented with only one class, so if I rewrite all the members in `class B` than the `interface A` becomes useless.

You may ask "Why you need `interface A` anyway?". I need it because I am using it from some other project, and I have to `extend` and `implement` it with some functions.

Any solution or different idea about that implementation?

Comment: You could use base class instead of interface (A) and use `class B extends A`. In this case you won't need to declare all these members in B

Comment: I shouldn't change the `interface A`, it is provided to me by another developer.

Comment: In this case you have to implement it..

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) like so:

```
interface A {
    id: string;
    name?: string;
    email?: string;
}

class B implements A {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    email: string;

    constructor(data: A) {
        Object.assign(this, data);
    }

    getName(): string {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3F%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20email%3F%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20B%20implements%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20email%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(data%3A%20A)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Object.assign(this%2C%20data)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20getName()%3A%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.name%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D))

Comment: Thanks, this might be very useful for me. Isn't there any way to get rid of rewriting `id`, `name`, `email`,.. in `class B`?

Comment: No, otherwise the compiler will complain that `B` fails to implement `A`